# Is MFC only available with Visual Studio, and not Visual C++ Express?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-express

Is MFC only available with Visual Studio, or is it also possible to use it with Visual C++ Express?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now there exists a solution to this problem, for all the people want to use a free version.

**Visual Studio Community 2013** comes with the MFC (Microsoft Foundation Classes) included. Download link: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

Edit: **Visual Studio Community 2015** is now also released.

Answer (score 7):

From the [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx):

> Does Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition
>   include MFC and ATL?
>
> No, MFC and ATL are not included with
>   Visual C++ 2008 Express. MFC and ATL
>   will be included in Visual Studio 2008
>   Standard and above editions.

Same for Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does that also mean there is no way to use MFC with the Express edition?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Indeed, there is no way of using it. And you shouldn't use it for new projects. It's old and evil.

Comment: @rubenvb it has been completely updated the last few releases and includes Windows 7 support and plenty more. It stayed stale for a decade, but it isn't any more. That said, I am not sure I would use it for a new project. Still, "you shouldn't use it for new projects" is too strong.

Comment: @Gregory: I speak out of no experience with it, but I came to understand that MFC locks you in more than provides you with unique features. Unless you're doing some core Win32 development (and then, still...) you should avoid using it.

Comment: @rubenvb, MFC is still the easiest way to throw together a C++ GUI quickly. Its age becomes an advantage when you look for existing solutions to your problems. Being close to the Windows API helps when you want to do something out of the ordinary. It's not a slam dunk anymore, but don't dismiss it out of hand.