# afxwin.h file is missing in VC++ Express Edition

Tags: visual-c++

When I try to run the file VC++ 2005 to VC++ 2008:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: canvas, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------  
1>Compiling...  
1>canvasApp.cpp  
1>c:\documents and settings\ram\my documents\visual studio 2008\demo\stdafx.h(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afxwin.h': No such file or directory  
1>canvasFrame.cpp  
1>c:\documents and settings\ram\my documents\visual studio 2008\demo\stdafx.h(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afxwin.h': No such file or directory  
1>Generating Code...  
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\ram\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\demo\Debug\BuildLog.htm"  
1>canvas - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)  
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found this post that may help:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/7c274008-80eb-42a0-a79b-95f5afbf6528/

Or shortly, afxwin.h is MFC and MFC is not included in the free version of VC++ (Express Edition).

Comment: This answer, despite being one of the top google results is highly outdated. MFC has been free since VS Community 2014.

Comment: Agree, but this answer was specific to Visual Studio 2008 as per the question.

Answer (score 14):

Including the header `afxwin.h` signalizes use of MFC. The following instructions (based on [those on CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30439/How-to-compile-MFC-code-in-Visual-C-Express)) could help to get MFC code compiling:

1. Download and install the [Windows Driver Kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit).
2. Select menu **Tools > Options… > Projects and Solutions > VC++ Directories**.
3. In the drop-down menu *Show directories for* select **Include files**.
4. Add the following paths (replace `$(WDK_directory)` with the directory where you installed Windows Driver Kit in the first step):

   ```
   $(WDK_directory)\inc\mfc42
   $(WDK_directory)\inc\atl30
   ```

   [image]
5. In the drop-down menu *Show directories for* select **Library files** and add (replace `$(WDK_directory)` like before):

   ```
   $(WDK_directory)\lib\mfc\i386
   $(WDK_directory)\lib\atl\i386
   ```

   [image]
6. In the `$(WDK_directory)\inc\mfc42\afxwin.inl` file, edit the following lines (starting from 1033):

   ```
   _AFXWIN_INLINE CMenu::operator==(const CMenu& menu) const
       { return ((HMENU) menu) == m_hMenu; }
   _AFXWIN_INLINE CMenu::operator!=(const CMenu& menu) const
       { return ((HMENU) menu) != m_hMenu; }
   ```

   to

   ```
   _AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CMenu::operator==(const CMenu& menu) const
       { return ((HMENU) menu) == m_hMenu; }
   _AFXWIN_INLINE BOOL CMenu::operator!=(const CMenu& menu) const
       { return ((HMENU) menu) != m_hMenu; }
   ```

   In other words, add `BOOL` after `_AFXWIN_INLINE`.

Comment: Step 5 is still needed. Your project may not use those lines, but they are buggy anyway and need to be fixed.

Comment: @malat I’ve edited my answer to directly include the updated instructions, please check it now.

Answer (score 7):

I see the question is about Express Edition, but this topic is easy to pop up in Google Search, and doesn't have a solution for other editions.

So. If you run into this problem with any VS Edition except Express, you can rerun installation and include MFC files.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. The easiest thing is to install the free Visual Studio Community 2015 as answered in this question
[Is MFC only available with Visual Studio, and not Visual C++ Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536627/is-mfc-only-available-with-visual-studio-and-not-visual-c-express)