# How can i open a vc++ procet in visual studio 2013 express ? Getting many errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a project that was written in vc++
One of the files is .sln and in the description I see: Microsoft Visual Studio Solution. When I open the file with visual studio 2013 express i'm getting many errors like it can't handle c++ or vc++

What should I do to be able to debug and work with the project in vc++ ?
Should I download vc++ from somewhere ? Or something for the visual studio 2013 express ?

Here is a screenshot of the files on my hard disk

[image: c++]

When I try to open the file VideoCaptureFilterSample.sln with visual studio 2013 express i'm getting more then 100 errors.
But it's not that the project realy have so many errors I think that visual studio 2013 express is for csharp and can't handle c++

Some of the errors i'm getting:

Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'afxwin.h': No such file or directory    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\videocapturefiltersample\stdafx.h   23  1   VideoCaptureFilterSample

```
2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "afxwin.h"    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\stdafx.h   23  1   VideoCaptureFilterSample
3   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "afxext.h"    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\stdafx.h   24  1   VideoCaptureFilterSample
4   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "afxdtctl.h"  e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\stdafx.h   31  1   VideoCaptureFilterSample
5   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "afxcmn.h"    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\stdafx.h   34  1   VideoCaptureFilterSample
8   IntelliSense: identifier "CWnd" is undefined    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\VideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg.cpp    19  60  VideoCaptureFilterSample
9   IntelliSense: "CDialog" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "CVideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg"    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\VideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg.cpp    20  4   VideoCaptureFilterSample
10  IntelliSense: expected a ')'    e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\VideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg.cpp    20  45  VideoCaptureFilterSample
11  IntelliSense: identifier "AfxGetApp" is undefined   e:\capturemaster\gamecapture-master\VideoCaptureFilterSample\VideoCaptureFilterSampleDlg.cpp    22  12  VideoCaptureFilterSample
```

Comment: Nothing will help us understand your problem better than _showing us the exact error messages_

Comment: paddy updated my question added a screenshot of the files. When I compile the project BUILD > Rebuild Solution i'm getting the errors. My guess visual studio 2013 express can't handle vc++

Comment: What @paddy was asking for was the actual error messages, not a screenshot of the files. You don't need to show all 100, maybe just the first few.

Comment: An image of the files on your disk is meaningless. What are the **specific errors** you're getting? We can't read your mind or see your screen from where we're sitting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [afxwin.h file is missing in VC++ Express Edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543523/afxwin-h-file-is-missing-in-vc-express-edition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install and use Visual Studio 2013 Community. As I know, Visual Studio Express do not include MFC headers.But you code has include afx*.h, which is a part of MFC.

Comment: Correct, Express editions have never included MFC or ATL. Even with VS Community, Professional, or higher you have to select support for MFC as part of the custom install--which for VS 2015 you are already having to do to get C++ at all :)