# Compiling with font resource

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources, directx-9

I'm on windows 8.1, visual studio 2017.

I'm using this pricedown font in a directx project I'm working on.

I load it with `AddFontResourceEx` and create a font for it with `D3DXCreateFont`.

When I hit "Local Windows Debugger" everything is fine, font renders. Be it in release or in debug mode.
Problem arises when I go through any executable, it never renders said font, be it release or debug.

So I went reading, I read the articles on msdn, [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e7446zd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and others whenever needed.

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, my Resource View looks like this:

[image: Resource View]

, and IDR_FONT1 looks like this:

[image]

The file is automatically loaded into the solution explorer (I didn't add it, VS did from the Resource.rc file), as you can see here:

[image]

With these proprieties:

[image]

I add it like so:

```
AddFontResourceEx("pricedown.ttf", FR_PRIVATE, 0);
this->createFont("Pricedown", 60, true, false);
```

Where createfont is my function to add the font (stripped down, it has arrays):

```
bool    D3D9Render::createFont(char *name, int size, bool bold, bool italic)
{
    D3DXCreateFont(m_pD3dDev, size, 0, (bold) ? FW_BOLD : FW_NORMAL, 0, (italic) ? 1 : 0, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, name, &m_pFont);
    return true;
}
```

I'm compiling it as x64 release.

As I've said, it works and renders the font when I press "Local Windows Debugger" (in any mode including x64 release), but when I go to `project/x64/Release`, it just won't render the font. Even the executable size is adequate.

`GetLastError` on the `AddFontResource` is 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using legacy Direct3D 9 if you are on Windows 8.1? Remember that ``D3DX9`` is deprecated, as is the DirectX SDK itself. If you are going to use the legacy DirectX SDK with VS 2017, be sure to read the bottom of the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for details on properly setting up the include/lib paths to mix an old DXSDK with the newer Windows 10 SDK you are using. See also [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Read the answer until the end, or you'll waste a lot of time.)

I got it. I had read over [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/fonthandlinganddetection/article.php/c16019/How-to-Use-a-Font-Without-Installing-It.htm) blog post.

> Here is an example on how to use AddFontMemResourceEx on a font file embedded in the resource.

```
HINSTANCE hResInstance = AfxGetResourceHandle( ); //Read the edit

HRSRC res = FindResource(
    hResInstance, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYFONT),
    L"BINARY"  //Read The Edit
); 
if (res) 
{
    HGLOBAL mem = LoadResource(hResInstance, res);
    void *data = LockResource(mem);
    size_t len = SizeofResource(hResInstance, res);

    DWORD nFonts;
    m_fonthandle = AddFontMemResourceEx(
        data,       // font resource
        len,       // number of bytes in font resource 
        NULL,          // Reserved. Must be 0.
        &nFonts      // number of fonts installed
        );

    if(m_fonthandle==0)
    {
        MessageBox(L"Font add fails", L"Error");
    }
}
```

<s>Though you need afxwin.h</s>, and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543523/afxwin-h-file-is-missing-in-vc-express-edition):

> afxwin.h is MFC and MFC is not included in the free version of VC++
>   (Express Edition)

---

**EDIT:**

You do not need to use `AfxGetResourceHandle` (why you would need `afxwin.h`), you can simply do:

```
HINSTANCE hResInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

And in `FindResource`, the 3rd parameter should be `RT_FONT`, and so you'd get:

```
HRSRC res = FindResource(hResInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_FONT1), RT_FONT);
```